# Property 'BN' does not exist on type 'Utils' web3js

Tags: web3js, bignumber

I am trying to convert a web3 BigNumber into an ethersjs BigNumber but I can't create a Web3 BigNumber variable.

I am typing

```
import Web3 from "web3";
const web3 = new Web3;
let BN = web3.utils.BN;
```

And I get this error `Property 'BN' does not exist on type 'Utils'.` I am using typescript. Any idea how to solve the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on [here](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/1597) about that but basically you have two options (only the first one worked for me)

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
```

Or just add on tsconfig.json

```
    "noImplicitAny": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

ethers.js have better typescript support , you should use ethers.js than web3 :>

You can also import BN.js instead since web3.js use BN.js under the hood

- https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/

```
const BN = require('bn.js');
```